# Telethon events in multithreading not working as expected

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, telethon

I wanted to run Telethon events in multi thread, multithreading.

For the following code, what I expected is multi thread, cocurrent independent events. `await asyncio.sleep( 3 )` will sleep 3 seconds. So If you send any text on telegram to the account, it will wait 3 seconds and send me back "hi.". I expected that if I send a text for several times at once, let's say 5 times, it should wait for approximately 3 seconds and send me "hi" back at once, but not like wait for 3 seconds, send "hi.", wait for 3 seconds, send "hi." .. for 5 times and takes approximately 15 seconds. This is not what I expected for.

So, How can I modify the code to run the code as expected? Or it's impossible in telethon?

I read google, stackoverflow, github issue, but couldn't find a solution by myself. So I want your help here. Thank you.

```py
import time
from pathlib import Path
import re
import random
import asyncio

from telethon import TelegramClient, events
from telethon.sessions import StringSession
from telethon import utils

import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR)

api_id = ""
api_hash = ''
phone = ''
string = Path('./string').read_text()

message = "hi."

if __name__ == '__main__':

    client = TelegramClient(StringSession(string), api_id, api_hash, sequential_updates=True)

    @client.on(events.NewMessage(incoming=True))
    async def handle_new_message(event):
        print('message:', event.message.message)
        # // not working here, the sleep blocks next events but not only current event. 
        print('wait for 3 seconds...')
        await asyncio.sleep( 3 )
        await event.respond(message)


    print('Auto-replying...')
    client.start(phone)
    client.run_until_disconnected()
    # client.loop.run_forever()

    # string = StringSession.save(client.session)
    # Path('./string').write_text(string)
```

Comment: @TheKill-996 you mean the code worked as expected? my python version is 3.6.7, and Telethon==1.18.2, tell me, what is your versions? thanks.

Comment: FWIW Telethon is not multi-threaded, it just uses multiple tasks by default to handle updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using sequential_updates so until the first update is not completed it will not move to other update. I guess you need to turn off sequential updates.

Comment: oh my god, so the answer was already there. my bad, should have read the code more carefully. you're a lifesaver, thank you.